# When executing JAR, I get Java program completed with exit code 1

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

I have a java classfile which has 'Hello World'.
I have created JAR file and Manifest file.
When I do a RUNJVA command with Classfile it works fine.
But when I try to use JAR file in RUNJVA, I don't see any output after the call.
Classpath is set properly.
I Just get 'Java program completed with exit code 1'

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try to run your jar file from cmd and see exactly what is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have a file `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` in your jar file that contains at least something like `Main-Class: full.qualified.name.of.MyClass` and start it with `java -cp {my-classpath-here} -jar myjarfile.jar`

Comment: Thanks for the reply
My Main-Class looks like below:
Main-Class: HelloWorld

And I am running using RUNJVA commad in command line with the JA file name and CLASSPATH with the IFS path name.
Still I get the same error.

I checked Manifest file of IBM Jar file like (IBMMisc.Jar) and I don't see any main class and when I try to run that Jar file too, i get the same error.

Comment: So provide the content of your Manifest and your Java Class

Comment: It works fine now.My bad Class name was case-sensitive.

The issue is resolved by adding the Main Class to Manifest file.

 Thanks a lot.